# angular receive reponse file for download

Tags: angularjs

I am using angular with laravel to generate some pdf files. I post some values to server and server responds with a file. now how to download the file from response.

i tried this method its not working

controller

```
Ecs.genSingleEcs(data).success(function(response){

    var file = new Blob([response], {type: 'application/pdf'});
    var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    $scope.ecsurl = fileURL;
});
```

view

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" ng-href="{{ ecsurl }}">Download</button>
```

response object

%PDF-1.3
    3 0 obj
    <>
    endobj
    4 0 obj
    <>
    stream
    x�3R��2�35W(�r
    Q�w3T04�30PISp
       �Z*�[����(hx����+���(j*�d���7W
    endstream
    endobj
    1 0 obj
    <

> >
>       endobj
>       5 0 obj
>       <
>       endobj
>       2 0 obj
>       <<
>       /ProcSet [/PDF /Text /ImageB /ImageC /ImageI]
>       /Font <<
>       /F1 5 0 R
>   >
>       /XObject <<
>   >
>   >
>       endobj
>       6 0 obj
>       <<
>       /Producer (FPDF 1.7)
>       /CreationDate (D:20141126070253)
>   >
>       endobj
>       7 0 obj
>       <<
>       /Type /Catalog
>       /Pages 1 0 R
>   >
>       endobj
>       xref
>       0 8
>       0000000000 65535 f 
>       0000000228 00000 n 
>       0000000416 00000 n 
>       0000000009 00000 n 
>       0000000087 00000 n 
>       0000000315 00000 n 
>       0000000520 00000 n 
>       0000000595 00000 n 
>       trailer
>       <<
>       /Size 8
>       /Root 7 0 R
>       /Info 6 0 R
>   >
>       startxref
>       644
>       %%EOF

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use:
https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/

And add this line of code to yours:

```
var file = new Blob([response], {type: 'application/pdf'});
var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
saveAs( blob, "myFileName.pdf");
```

I am already using this in my AngularJS app

Comment: is it a typo `saveAs( blob, "myFileName.pdf");` should it be 'saveAs( file, "myFileName.pdf");' . I tried got no response. going to try harder